# Django rest framework nested data receiving from JavaScript nested form-data

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

## My problem is that creating nested form-data and receiving them.

Here is my models.py:

```
class BridgeReport(models.Model):
    bridge = models.ForeignKey(Bridgedata, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='report')
    title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class MajorInspection(models.Model):
    major_inspection = ForeignKey(BridgeReport, related_name='major_inspection', on_delete=CASCADE)
    damaged_member = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    grade = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True) # choice
   
class MajorInspectionReport(models.Model):
    major_inspection_report = ForeignKey(MajorInspection, related_name='major_inspection_report', on_delete=CASCADE)
    defect_type = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    cause = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    maintenance_and_reinforcement_plan = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    special_note = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    attached_file = models.ImageField(upload_to = custom_upload_to_MajorInspection, blank=True)
```

Here is my serializers.py

```
class MajorInspectionReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    class Meta:
        model = MajorInspectionReport
        exclude = ['major_inspection_report']
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Handle the creation of a MajorInspectionReport instance here
        return MajorInspectionReport.objects.create(**validated_data)

class MajorInspectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    major_inspection_report = MajorInspectionReportSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
        
    major_inspection_reports = serializers.ListField(
    child = CustomField(), 
    write_only = True, required=False
    )
    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("1Validate data", validated_data)
        major_inspection_reports = validated_data.pop("major_inspection_reports")
        major_inspection_report = MajorInspection.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if major_inspection_reports:       
            print("2major_inspection_reports: ",major_inspection_reports)        
            for dic in major_inspection_reports:
                
                print("3mana:",dic.get('[defect_type]', ''))
                print("dic is ", dic)
                MajorInspectionReport.objects.create(
                major_inspection_report=major_inspection_report,
                defect_type=dic.get('[defect_type]', ''),
                cause=dic.get('[cause]', ''),
                maintenance_and_reinforcement_plan=dic.get('[maintenance_and_reinforcement_plan]', ''),
                special_note=dic.get('[special_note]', ''),
                attached_file=dic.get('[attached_file]', ''),
                )
                
            return major_inspection_report
        return MajorInspection.objects.create(**validated_data)

    
    class Meta:
            model = MajorInspection
            exclude = ['major_inspection'] 


class BridgeReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    major_inspection = MajorInspectionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, required=False)
    model_3d = ThreeDModelSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, required=False)
    
    
    upload_major_inspections = serializers.ListField(
    child = CustomField(), 
    write_only = True, required=False
    )
    class Meta:
        model = BridgeReport
        exclude = ['bridge']
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("1Validate data", validated_data)
        
        upload_major_inspections = validated_data.pop("upload_major_inspections")
        uploaded_file_model_3d = validated_data.get("uploaded_file_model_3d")

        if upload_major_inspections:
            print(upload_major_inspections)
            major_inspection = BridgeReport.objects.create(**validated_data)
            for df in upload_major_inspections:
                # print("damage:",df.get('[damaged_member]', ''))
                # print("grade:", df.get('[grade]', '')) 
                major_inspection_id = MajorInspection.objects.create(major_inspection=major_inspection,damaged_member = df.get('damaged_member',''), grade = df.get('grade',''))
                # print("major_inspection_reports-->", df.get('major_inspection_reports', ''))    
                # print("major_inspection_id-->", major_inspection_id)
                
                # for mj in df.get('major_inspection_reports', ''):
                #     print("major_inspection_reports-->for-->", mj)
                
                # if["major_inspection_reports"]:       
                #     for dic in df.get(["major_inspection_reports"], ""):
                #         print("3mana:",dic.get('[defect_type]', ''))
                #         print("dic is ", dic)
                #         MajorInspectionReport.objects.create(
                #         major_inspection_report=major_inspection_report,
                #         defect_type=dic.get('[defect_type]', ''),
                #         cause=dic.get('[cause]', ''),
                #         maintenance_and_reinforcement_plan=dic.get('[maintenance_and_reinforcement_plan]', ''),
                #         special_note=dic.get('[special_note]', ''),
                #         attached_file=dic.get('[attached_file]', ''),
                #         )      
                  #  return major_inspection_report
                return major_inspection
            
       
        
        return BridgeReport.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Every time when validated_data is received, validated_data is being printed so that I can check the data, but I am not receiving iterable data in order to create MajorInspection. So I need to re-edit my serializer in order to receive nested JavaScript form-data properly. And I need JavaScript simple code that sends nested form-data.